# SQL performance issues with remote query across linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

This sproc

```
create proc dbo.Get_Accounts as
begin
  declare @current_date datetime
  set @current_date = dbo.fn_currdate()

  select [fields]
  into dbo.current_accounts
  from linkedserver.database.dbo.accounts
  where date = @current_date
end
```

continually fails after 10 minutes with the following error message:

> Server: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 OLE DB provider 'SQLOLEDB'
>   reported an error. Execution terminated by the provider because a
>   resource limit was reached. [OLE/DB provider returned message: Timeout
>   expired] OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'SQLOLEDB'
>   ICommandText::Execute returned 0x80040e31: Execution terminated by the
>   provider because a resource limit was reached.].

However, when I run the same query from the same database (not on the remote one) in an interactive query window with the date hard-coded:

```
  select [fields]
  into dbo.current_accounts
  from linkedserver.database.dbo.accounts
  where date = '1/20/2012'
```

It returns in 30 seconds.

The local server is SQLSERVER 2008, the remote is SQLSERVER 2000.

We have done the following to no avail:

- Recreated the stored proc.
- sp_recompile on the stored proc
- update statistics on dbo.accounts
- dropped and recreated the indexes on dbo.accounts
- dropped the index on dbo.accounts and try
- DBCC FREEPROCCACHE & DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS on both local and remote servers
- Rebooted the remote server (not an easy option on the local one)

Questions

- Can anyone explain this bizarre behavior?
- Any suggestions on other options for correcting it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can turn on [trace flag 7300](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314530) which *might* give you a more detailed error message

How many rows does a representative query return? How fast/reliable is the network connection between the two servers?

It's possible that a large dataset is taking too long to transfer (on top of the actual query time).  You could raise the timeout value.

You can try to reconfigure the timeout setting as follows:

Set the remote login timeout to 300 seconds:

```
sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 300
go 
reconfigure with override 
go
```

Set the remote query timeout to 0 (infinite wait):

```
sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0 
go 
reconfigure with override 
go
```

**Update**: **SQL Server 2012 SP1 onwards**: users with `SELECT` permission will be able to access `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` which will improve read only performance on linked servers. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384(v=sql.110).aspx

**Update**:  You are correct in saying it's not the size of data or connection speed.  It rang a bell in my foggy memory and I remembered where I had seen it: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)(An Issue With Linked Servers). It's not parameter sniffing, it is the statistics themselves that are missing (due to permissions), causing a bad query plan to be used:

> You can see that the estimates are different. When I ran as sysadmin,
>   the estimate was 1 row, which is a correct number, since there are no
>   Orders in Northwind where the order ID exceeds 20000. But when I ran
>   as a plain user, the estimate was 249 rows. We recognize this
>   particular number as 30 % of 830 orders, or the estimate for an
>   inequality operation when the optimizer has no information.
>   Previously, this was due to an unknown variable value, but in this
>   case there is no variable that can be unknown. No, it is the
>   statistics themselves that are missing.
>
> As long as a query accesses only tables in the local server, the
>   optimizer can always access the statistics for all tables in the
>   query; there are no extra permission checks. But this is different
>   with tables on a linked server. When SQL Server accesses a linked
>   server, there is no secret protocol that is only used for inter-server
>   communication. No, instead SQL Server uses the standard OLE DB
>   interface for linked servers, be other SQL Server instances, Oracle,
>   text files or your home-brewed data source, and connects just like any
>   other user. Exactly how statistics is retrieved depends on the data
>   source and the OLE DB provider in question. In this case, the provider
>   is SQL Server Native Client which retrieves the statistics in two
>   steps. (You can see this by running Profiler against the remote
>   server). First the provider runs the procedure
>   sp_table_statistics2_rowset which returns information about which
>   column statistics there are, as well as their cardinality and their
>   density information. In the second step, the provider runs DBCC
>   SHOW_STATISTICS, a command that returns the full distribution
>   statistics. (We will look closer at this command later in this
>   article.) Here is the catch: to run DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS, you must be
>   member of the server role sysadmin or any of the database roles
>   db_owner or db_ddladmin.
>
> And this is why I got different results. When running as sysadmin I
>   got the full distribution statistics which indicated that there are no
>   rows with order ID > 20000, and the estimate was one row. (Recall that
>   the optimizer never assumes zero rows from statistics.) But when
>   running as the plain user, DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS failed with a
>   permission error. This error was not propagated, but instead the
>   optimizer accepted that there were no statistics and used default
>   assumptions. Since it did get cardinality information, it learnt that
>   the remote table has 830 rows, whence the estimate of 249 rows.
>
> Whenever you encounter a performance problem where a query that
>   includes access to a linked server is slow in the application, but it
>   runs fast when you test it from SSMS, you should always investigate if
>   insufficient permissions on the remote database could be the cause.
>   (Keep in mind that the access to the linked server may not be overt in
>   the query, but could be hidden in a view.) If you determine that
>   permissions on the remote database is the problem, what actions could
>   you take?
>
> - You can add the users to the role db_ddladmin, but since this gives them right to add and drop tables, this is not recommendable.
> - By default, when a users connect to a remote server they connect as themselves, but you can set up a login mapping with
>     sp_addlinkedsrvlogin, so that users map to a proxy account that has
>     membership in db_ddladmin. Note that this proxy account must be an SQL
>     login, so this is not an option if the remote server does not have SQL
>     authentication enabled. This solution too is somewhat dubious from a
>     security perspective, although its better the previous suggestion.
> - In some cases you can rewrite the query with OPENQUERY to force evaluation on the remote server. This can be particularly useful, if
>     the query includes several remote tables. (But it can also backfire,
>     because the optimizer now gets even less statistics information from
>     the remote server.)
> - You could of course use the full battery of hints and plan guides to get the plan you want.
> - Finally, you should ask yourself whether that linked-server access is needed. Maybe the databases could be on the same server? Could data
>     be replicated? Some other solution?

Comment: It returns about 140k records.  but since it works just fine when the date value is hardcoded I can't think of a I/O or network issue that would affect the parameterized version so extremely.  My gut says that the query is being passed to the remote server and the remote optimizer somehow chooses a bad query plan when it can't make sense of the parameter.  But reindexing and purging the cache/buffers should correct that (I assume).


I'll look into timeouts to see if we can make it at least return.

Thanks

Comment: Excellent answer and explained exactly the problem I was having, thanks. I would add that [according to the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384(v=sql.110).aspx), from SQL2012 SP1 onwards users with `SELECT` permission will be able to access `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` which will improve read only performance on linked servers without having to compromise security.

Answer (score 2):

I have two ideas that might help. I'm also going to tell you that I've had mixed to bad luck with performance running queries against linked servers. So my first recommendation is to avoid it if you can.

My first idea is to install the stored procedure into the SQL Server 2000 box, having it reference the local server. You can then execute the stored procedure remotely.

```
exec linkedserver.database.dbo.Get_Accounts
```

If you can go this route, it should improve performance tremendously.

My second idea is to get at the estimated query plan when running the stored procedure. Is it showing you what is taking so much time? One potential problem is that the account you are using on the linked server might not have enough authority to get at the table statistics (you need more authority for the linked server than you do for the local server). And that can make queries unbelievably slow. You can read more about that particular problem [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2010/11/23/linked-servers-permissions-and-distributed-query-performance.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try this (i.e. explicitly indicate what should be run on the remote server)?:

```
select [fields]
into dbo.current_accounts
from OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'SELECT [fields] FROM database.dbo.accounts where date = ''1/20/2012''');
```

I suspect in your case above SQL Server is just pulling the whole table from the remote server then running the query locally (I have seen this happen many times in the past). I prefer to be explicit (either by using OPENQUERY or by creating a SP on the remote server) so there is no chance of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a ressource issue , the memory pool outside SQL server used to load external drivers and the CLR might be close to its limit. The default is 256MB. To get around this I suggest that you go to SQL server configuration manager, advanced tab and add the -g option to the end of the startup parameters.i.e ;-g1024 then restart the SQL Server service. I usually do  this as we use a high number of linked server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx